# 'HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden' with Python 3.6.1

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse this page:http://www.chronicle.com/article/Major-Private-Gifts-to-Higher/128264 with BeautifulSoup4 on iPython. I wrote these lines of code:

```
import urllib.request as ur
import re
page = ur.urlopen('http://www.chronicle.com/article/Major-Private-Gifts-to-Higher/128264').read()
```

And then I got this error:

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-27-8d5066f9c76f> in <module>()
----> 1 s = ur.urlopen("http://www.chronicle.com/article/Major-Private-
Gifts-to-Higher/128264")

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, 
data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 
    225 def install_opener(opener):

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in open(self, 
fullurl, data, timeout)
    530         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    531             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 532             response = meth(req, response)
    533 
    534         return response

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in 
http_response(self, request, response)
    640         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    641             response = self.parent.error(
--> 642                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    643 
    644         return response

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in error(self, 
proto, *args)
568         if http_err:
569             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + 
orig_args
--> 570             return self._call_chain(*args)
571 
572 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it 
makes

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in 
_call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
502         for handler in handlers:
503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
505             if result is not None:
506                 return result

/Users/name/anaconda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py in 
http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    648 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    649     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
 --> 650         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    651 
    652 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Using the requests module is much easier and has been proven easier to use.

The issue, however, is what the previous Stackoverflow user said, it does require some headers and such. The module `requests` has inbuild support for such as far as I'm aware. Note that instead of `.read()` the method we use is`.text`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

urlopen = requests.get('http://www.chronicle.com/article/Major-Private-Gifts-to-Higher/128264').text
soup = bs(urlopen,'lxml')

print(soup)
```

you don't need to parse it with beautfiulSoup you can just...

```
import requests

urlopen = requests.get('http://www.chronicle.com/article/Major-Private-Gifts-to-Higher/128264').text
print(urlopen)
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to send the required HTTP headers as well. Have a look at the headers that for example Firefox sends to the page by using the dev tools of the browser. Add those to the request. I guess at least User-Agent is one of the headers that have to be set.